# JSON. JAVA and PHP cheack if form value exist

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a html form where the user has to insert a color.
Under the form I entered this javascript:

```
function verify_color(){

    var color = encodeURI($("#form_color").val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"JSON",
        url: "colors_ajax.php",
        async: false,
        data: {colors:colors},
        success: function(response){

            $("#colors_ok").hide();
            $("#colors__error").hide();

            //console.log(response);
            if (response.success == 1) $("#colors_ok").show();
            else if (response.success == 0) $("#colors_error").show();     
        }
    });
}
```

How can I create the `colors_ajax.php` file containing the colors in json data that give me the response `{"success": 0}` or `{"success": 1}`

if the color inserted in the form is contained in the list?
thank you very much

Comment: I would start by fixing the TYPO's. Like `data: {colors:colors},` changed to `data: {colors:color},`

Comment: $_POST['colors'] and then check whatever you want, if ok just echo something, else abort(404)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Exa

Answer (score 0):

First change `data: {colors:colors},` to `data: {color:color},` because your variable is `color`.
Then you can create an array with the color you want and then check if the color submitted is inside that array:

```php
<?php
$colors = [
    '#000000',
    ....
];
$_POST['color'] && in_array($_POST['color'], $colors) ? echo "{success :1}" : echo "{success :0}";
/*
same of

if($_POST['color'] && in_array($_POST['color'], $colors)) echo "{success :1}" ;
else echo "{success :0}" ;

*/
```

Comment: Questioner was quite precise about the response they required, saying they wanted `{"success": 0} or {"success": 1}`